# How to dynamically prune Java List when Iterator does not support remove()?

Tags: java, list, iterator

I have the following code:

```
Widget[] widgetArray = widgetService.getAllWidgets();
List<Widget> widgets = Arrays.asList(widgetArray);

// Prune out any Widgets named "Melvin".
Iterator<Widget> iter = widgets.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Widget w = iter.next();

    if("Melvin".equals(w.getName()))
        iter.remove();
}
```

When I run this code I get a runtime `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationExceptionError` with a vague exception message of `null` that gets thrown on the `iter.remove()` line. It seems that some Java `Iterators` don't support the `remove` method and will throw this exception.

I can't change the `widgetService.getAllWidgets()` method to return a `List<Widget>` and am stuck with the `Widget[]` array return value.

So I ask: what can I do to loop through my `widgets` array and dynamically prune out ones that are named "*Melvin*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can afford it, just make a mutable copy of the list. Replace

```
List<Widget> widgets = Arrays.asList(widgetArray);
```

with

```
List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>(Arrays.asList(widgetArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just defer removal until the iterator is done:

```
Widget[] widgetArray = widgetService.getAllWidgets();
List<Widget> widgets = Arrays.asList(widgetArray);

// Prune out any Widgets named "Melvin".
List<Widget> toRemove = new ArrayList<Widget>();
Iterator<Widget> iter = widgets.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Widget w = iter.next();

    if("Melvin".equals(w.getName()))
        toRemove.add(w);
}
widgets.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Alternatively, just build the list from eligible widgets using the inverse logic:

```
List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();
// Add all Widgets not named "Melvin"
for (Widget w : widgetService.getAllWidgets()) {
    if(!"Melvin".equals(w.getName()))
        widgets.add(w);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ted Hopp (+1) - I thought of that too (the concept of a "to remove" 2ndary list), I guess I'm just finding it hard to believe that Java doesn't have something a little more elegant baked in...

Comment: The `widgets` List is a fixed-size "list view of the specified array" (see JavaDoc) and cannot remove entries, because you cannot remove entries from an array. Even `widgets.removeAll(...)` should fail for the same reason (didn't test it). So the way to go would be to follow Guido Simone's answer (copy all into a fresh `ArrayList` and then prune), or your second solution (copy filtered).

Comment: Yes I can confirm that the `widgets.removeAll(...)` fails for the same reason. Implementing @Guido Simone's solution...

Answer (score 1):

The `asList()` list is still backed by the array.

You may want to loop through each element of the array and add it to a brand new list.  This would take two loops.

Or better yet, compare the string value and then add to the list.  This way, you have one loop and a brand new list.

Comment: Saw the first answer too late. Almost same as above.

Answer (score 0):

With [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you can get rid of all that code and let a fast, well tested library take care of it for you.

```
Collection<Widget> noMelvins = Collections2.filter( Arrays.asList(widgetArray), new Predicate<Widget>() {
    @Override public boolean apply( final Widget arg) {
        return !"Melvin".equals(arg.getName());
    }
});
```

Comment: adding new libaries to a project is not necessary for this

Comment: A downvote for suggesting a tool that's explicitly made for this situation?  Odd judgement. Who's to say guava isn't already in the project or that he's not doing something similar in 25 other places in the project? Plenty of other viewers may find value in this answer. Nothing wrong with adding another tool to the bag.

Comment: Although I didn't use your suggestion, agreed (+1)

Comment: [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) has a very similar utility with [`CollectionUtils.filter()`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29)